# Bad Flag Delimiters on .htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've entered the following into my .htaccess and I'm getting the dreaded bad flag delimiters error.  I've tried validators, and one says it's lines 5 and 7, another says all the other lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.php HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^source= RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^business/([^/.]+)/?$ business.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^event/([^/.]+)/?$ event.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Space is not allowed unescaped. Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /category.php\?id=([^&\ ]+) HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ /category/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^source=
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^business/([^/.]+)/?$ business.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^event/([^/.]+)/?$ event.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That is still giving me the bad flag delimiters error, specifically at the THE_REQUEST line

Comment: it validated, but the rewriterules to change category.php?id=1 to category/1 still do not work.

Comment: There is no rule to redirect `category.php?id=1 to category/1` in your code. I am adding one for this. Try it now.